# Как постоянно передавать данные с бэк энда в андройд приложение?

Tags: php, сервер

Допустим есть андройд приложение, на стороне сервера идет расчет определенного значения (на php), и это значение должно постоянно отображаться в приложении. С помощью чего можно организовать постоянную передачу данных с сервера в андройд приложение. 
Извиняюсь если вопрос не корректен, благодарен за любые ответы.

Comment: Через сокет можно в реалтайм режиме обмениваться данными. Опять же, никакой конкретики в вашем вопросе нет и неизвестно какие данные и нужно ли это вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно применить несколько подходов:

1. Продублировать бизнес логику, и на бэкэнде и в приложение, позже сравнивать полученные значения. Либо предварительно делать расчет динамический а в результате уже более точный расчет брать с бекэнда.
2. Поднять веб-сокет и работать через него, но веб-сокеты сложны в плане написания демона и поддержание его работы, так же есть проблема с разграничениями по сессиям.
3. Пересмотреть логику работы приложения, если возникают такие вопросы, скорее всего есть какие либо архитектурные погрешности.